# Leak of database connections with Hibernate: 4.2.21 and Jboss 6.4.21

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jboss, jboss6.x

The version **Jboss 6.4.21EAP** with **Hibernate: 4.2.21.Final** in spite of opening and closing the sessions (finally clause), creates connections **INACTIVE/idle** in our database **Oracle Database 12c** Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Next I put our configuration in hibernate

> ```
> <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
> <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
> <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
> <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
> <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
> <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
> <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
> <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/myapp</property>
> <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property>
> ```

```
public void  addApplication (Application application) {
        Session session = MyAppSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(application);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in addApplication: ", e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

From what we have seen Hibernate retains the connection in the JBoss pool, and obviously the problem is when the maximum defined in our pool-size is reached, the application has this exception:

**Log on Jboss**

> javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections
>   available within configured blocking timeout (60000 [ms])

**Logs on Oracle**
[image]

Apparently it seems a **leak of database connections in code**, but we have reviewed our code a thousand times and all connections open and close properly.

We have seen this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645435/database-connections-not-closed-after-idle-timeout-in-wildfly-datasource), and we have tried to put the parameter to **AFTER_TRANSACTION** and we have seen a strange behavior also, the application does not have the error: **ResourceException: IJ000655** anymore, but in the database we have the same number of connections IDLE == to our max jboss pool size, but the application can still connect when in theory it should not ...

This behavior is a BUG of Jboss with that version of Hibernate?

Despite the strange behavior with **Hibernate Release Mode = after_transaction**, is it advisable to change the default mode release?